# Method overrides with Func<T,M> and Action<T> in C#

Tags: c#, methods, overriding

I have the following two methods which work:

```
    public T InvokeFunc<T>(Func<ServiceClient,T> operation)
    {
        return operation(client);
    }

    public void InvokeAction(Action<ServiceClient> operation)
    {
        operation(client);
    }
```

Is there a way to make these methods override each other, with the compiler being able to distinguish which one I am trying to use?

This is what I have tried:

```
    public void InvokeOperation(Action<RimsoftHRServiceClient> operation)
    {
        operation(client);
    }

    public T InvokeOperation<T>(Func<RimsoftHRServiceClient,T> operation)
    {
        operation(client);
    }
```

but when I try to use any of the two methods I get an error saying the compiler can't recognize which method I want to use.

I want to do something like this:

```
 List<City> cities = InvokeOperation(x => x.GetAllCities()); //GetAllCities returns List<City>
```

But also be able to do this too:

```
InvokeOperation(x=>x.TestCommunication()); //TestCommunication returns void
```

Is that possible or do I have to use different names for both methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to do this .

The specification states that C # Methods Overloaded must have different parameters , as seen in the link below ,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229029.aspx

It makes sense , after all, how would he know which method you are using before being compiled ? This could generate an exception at runtime

Hope this helps

Comment: Very simply, it's Impossible. Why you down-me?

Comment: You are correct but in my case the parameters are of different type. One is of type Func<ServiceClient,T> and the other is of type Action<ServiceClient>. Maybe those are in fact not considered different because of their similar call signatures. I will wait for some more answers to get a few other opinions.

Comment: Your question is deeper than I could imagine. I think what is happening is that both methods are given as parameter a delegate. In this case , the compiler can not differ between one another . As much as their parameters signatur are not equal , both represent a delegate

Comment: @Joao. Counter voted Phoenix. Someone being told what they seek is not possible and being provided supporting evidence/argument shouldn't result in a downvote simply because they aren't getting what they what.